# Accessing class values in R's poLCA

Tags: r

I am trying my hand at learning Latent Component Analysis, while also learning R. I'm using the [poLCA package](http://dlinzer.github.io/poLCA/), and am having a bit of trouble accessing the attributes. I can run the [sample code](http://www.r-bloggers.com/example-8-21-latent-class-analysis/) just fine:

```
ds = read.csv("http://www.math.smith.edu/r/data/help.csv")
ds = within(ds, (cesdcut = ifelse(cesd>20, 1, 0)))

library(poLCA)
res2 = poLCA(cbind(homeless=homeless+1, 
    cesdcut=cesdcut+1, satreat=satreat+1, 
    linkstatus=linkstatus+1) ~ 1, 
    maxiter=50000, nclass=3, 
    nrep=10, data=ds)
```

but in order to make this more useful, I'd like to access the attributes within the objects created by the poLCA class as such:

```
attr(res2, 'Nobs')
attr(res2, 'maxiter')
```

but they both come up as 'Null'. I expect Nobs to be 453 (determined by the function) and maxiter to be 50000 (dictated by my input value).

I'm sure I'm just being naive, but I could use any help available. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Link to data is broken. Do you have any backup of this data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to R. You've got the model-fitting syntax right, in that you can get a model out (don't know how latent component analysis works, so can't speak to the statistical validity of your result). However, you've mixed up the different ways in which R can store information pertaining to a model.

`poLCA` returns an object of class `poLCA`, which is

> a list containing the following elements:
>
> (. . .)
>
> `Nobs` number of fully observed cases (less than or equal to N).
>
> `maxiter` maximum number of iterations through which the estimation algorithm was set
>   to run.

Since it's a list, you can extract individual elements from your model object using the `$` operator:

```
res2$Nobs      # number of observations
res2$maxiter   # maximum iterations
```

In some cases, there might be extractor functions to get this information without having to do low-level indexing. For example, many model-fitting functions will have a `fitted` method, which pulls out the vector of fitted values on the training data; and similarly `residuals` pulls out the vector of residuals. You should check whether there are such extractor functions provided by the `poLCA` package and use them if possible; that way, you're not making assumptions about the structure of the model object that might be broken in the future.

This is distinct to getting the *attributes* of an object, which is what you use `attr` for. Attributes in R are what you might call metadata: they contain R-specific information about an object itself, rather than information about whatever it is the object relates to. Examples of common attributes include `class` (the class of an object), `dim` (the dimensions of an array or matrix), `names` (names of individual elements of a vector/list/array) and so on.

Comment: Ah, makes sense now. thanks for such a detailed answer. I'd up-vote you, but my reputation is too low to allow it.